# Helm chart failed to download

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When trying to do a list on helm by below command I am able to see the list of charts currently deployed in GKE cluster

```
helm list --all-namespaces

NAME    NAMESPACE REVISION    UPDATED       STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
abc-cd  in-gke    1           2023-01-06    deployed        cd-5.16.14      v2.5.5
```

However when trying to download , it's throwing download error

```
$ helm show chart cd-5.16.14
Error: failed to download "cd-5.16.14"
```

Also helm repo showing blank , not sure if this has any significance as I can already see the charts

```
$ helm repo list
Error: no repositories to show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`helm list --all-namespaces` shows the `releases` that are already installed in your k8s cluster, and [`helm show`](https://This%20command%20lists%20all%20of%20the%20releases%20for%20a%20specified%20namespace%20(uses%20current%20namespace%20context%20if%20namespace%20not%20specified).) shows information about the chart.

> "*A Chart is a Helm package. It contains all of the resource definitions
> necessary to run an application, tool, or service inside of a
> Kubernetes cluster.*
>
> *A Repository is the place where charts can be collected and shared.*
>
> *A Release is an instance of a chart running in a Kubernetes cluster.
> One chart can often be installed many times into the same cluster. And
> each time it is installed, a new release is created.*"
> - from [Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#three-big-concepts)

Now if you are getting no response from `helm repo list` means that you need to add local repositories, and then you may need to update them. To do that use:

- [`helm repo add [NAME] [URL] [flags]`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_repo_add/#helm) To add a repository.
- [`helm repo update [REPO1 [REPO2 ...]] [flags]`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_repo_update/#helm) To update the information on available charts locally from chart repositories.

If it didn't work for some reasons, you may try `helm repo add` with `--force-update` as recommended in different troubleshooting scenarios here: https://helm.sh/docs/faq/troubleshooting/

If it worked you would be able to run `helm show REPO_NAME/CHART_NAME`.

---

In case you lost access to the chart or its repository, or it was deployed from a local helm chart that was not published to an artifactory. You can get the rendered manifest with `helm get manifest RELEASE`, with your example's inputs it will be:

```
helm get manifest abc-cd --namespace in-gke
```

And this won't show your `helm values` to get that you can try with [`helm get values RELEASE_NAME [flags]`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_get_values/#helm), which would be something like:

```
helm get values abc-cd --namespace in-gke --all
```

---

Also, if any of these commands fail add `--debug` or set `HELM_DEBUG=1`.

I hope this was helpful :)

Comment: This helped a lot to understand , thank you so much